# Tab order using Assignment dialog box in VS 2022

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2022, tabindex

I'm new to Visual Studio 2022.
In my old VS Version 2010 I could easily change the tab order for a Windows Form using "View" and the point "dialog box". [Like here](https://tobiasloeser.de/die-unterschaetzte-aktivierreihenfolge/)

In VS 2022 I couldn't find that point?
I know I can change the tab order with the property TabIndex. But if I have 10-20 controls on a form I would prefer the other way.
So, can someone tell me if there is such a point in VS 2022 - and where?

Comment: This functionality is still present in my View drop down.  It's pretty far down in the list https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZAO8.png.  Additionally, search "Tab Order" in the search bar at the top of Visual Studio and it should pop up in the results (as well as where to find it).

Comment: did you figure it out? as my VS2022 also missing the Tab Order under View.

Answer (score 0):

Today, [Tab Order] (Ctrl-D) is under the [Format] menu.